# Задать разрешение экрана в bash скрипте при включенной опции дробное масштабирование в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, wine

У меня включена опция дробного масштабирования в **pop_os!** на 125%. Скрипт при запуске определяет мое разрешение как 3072x1728 (на самом деле мой лэптом поддерживает только 1920x1080). Из за этого игра которую я запускают открывается в разрешении 3072x1728 больше чем на пол экрана моего лэптопа. При запуске скрипт определяет мое разрешение как: **Current desktop resolution: 3072x1728**, а мне нужно что бы было 1920x1080. Вот кусок кода, который я так понимаю отвечает за это:

```
get_desktop_res()
{
    if (type xrandr &>/dev/null) ; then
        local NUM_CONNECTED_OUTPUTS=0
        DESKTOP_RES=$(xrandr -q | awk -F'current|,' 'NR==1 {gsub(" ","");print $3}')
        echo "Current desktop resolution: $DESKTOP_RES"
        local TEMPSTR=$(xrandr -q | grep 'connected')
        DISPLAY_OUTPUTS=($(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$TEMPSTR"))
        DISPLAY_RESLIST=($(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$TEMPSTR"))
        for ((X=0 ; X < ${#DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[@]} ; X++)) ; do
            if [ "${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}" == "connected" ] ; then
                DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]=$(grep "^${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]}" <<<"$TEMPSTR" | grep -o "[0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\}")
                ((NUM_CONNECTED_OUTPUTS++))
            else
                DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]=""
            fi
        done
        echo "Detected $X display output(s). Connected outputs:"
        for ((X=0 ; X < ${#DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[@]} ; X++)) ; do
            if [ "${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}" != "" ] ; then
                printf "${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]}: ${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}"
                if [ "$CURRENT_RES" == "" ] && ([[ "$(awk NR==$((X+1)) <<< "$TEMPSTR")" =~ "primary" ]] || [ "$NUM_CONNECTED_OUTPUTS" == "1" ]) ; then
                    printf " (primary)\n"
                    CURRENT_RES=${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}
                else
                    printf "\n"
                fi
            fi
        done
        if [ "$CURRENT_RES" == "" ] ; then
            if [ "$DESKTOP_RES" != "" ] ; then
                echo "WARNING: Could not determine the primary display resolution. Using desktop resolution as fallback."
                CURRENT_RES=$DESKTOP_RES
            fi
        fi
        CURRENT_RES_X=$(awk -F'x' '{print $1}' <<<"$CURRENT_RES")
        CURRENT_RES_Y=$(awk -F'x' '{print $2}' <<<"$CURRENT_RES")
    else
        echo "ERROR: Unable to read the display information."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Возможно это тоже нужно править...

```
check_res()
{
    if [ "$DESKTOP_RES" != "" ] ; then
        if [ "$(xrandr -q | awk -F'current|,' 'NR==1 {gsub(" ","");print $3}')" != "$DESKTOP_RES" ] ; then
            echo "Discrepancy between current and original desktop resolution. Attempting to restore..." >&2
            xrandr -s $DESKTOP_RES
        fi
        local TEMPSTR=$(xrandr -q | grep 'connected')
        local DISPLAY_OUTPUTS_TMP=($(awk '{print $1}' <<<"$TEMPSTR"))
        local DISPLAY_RESLIST_TMP=($(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$TEMPSTR"))
        for ((X=0 ; X < ${#DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[@]} ; X++)) ; do
            if [ "${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS_TMP[$X]}" == "${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]}" ] ; then
                if [ "${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}" != "" ] && [ "${DISPLAY_RESLIST_TMP[$X]}" == "connected" ] && [ "$(grep "${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS_TMP[$X]}" <<<"$TEMPSTR" | grep -o "[0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\}")" != "${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}" ] ; then
                    echo "Discrepancy between current and original setting for display output ${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]}. Attempting to restore..." >&2
                    xrandr --output ${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]} --mode ${DISPLAY_RESLIST[$X]}
                fi
            else
                echo "Display output mismatch: cannot check/restore ${DISPLAY_OUTPUTS[$X]}" >&2
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3072 x 1728, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 3072x1728+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: так запустите сценарий через bash -x и подправьте где нужно

Comment: Спасибо, полезная команда, но я не знаю как мне подправить скрипт :)